# Extract body text from Email PHP

Tags: php, imap

I am currently using an imap stream to get emails from an inbox.

Everything is working fine except I am unsure how to get the body text and title of the email.  If I do `imap_body($connection,$message)` the base 64 equivalent of the email attachment is included in the text.

I am currently using this function to get the attachments.

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/function-extract-email-attachments-php-imap/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Well php imap's function are not fun to work with.  A user on this page explains the inconsistencies with getting emails: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchbody.php#89002

Using his helpful information I created a reliably way to get an email's body text.

```
$bodyText = imap_fetchbody($connection,$emailnumber,1.2);
if(!strlen($bodyText)>0){
    $bodyText = imap_fetchbody($connection,$emailnumber,1);
}
$subject = imap_headerinfo($connection,$i);
$subject = $subject->subject;

echo $subject."\n".$bodyText;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. After googling for 4 hours I found the working example.

Comment: What is that `1.2` all about?

Comment: @pguardiario I have no idea although if you click on the link above it might help some.  I believe I got to the solution with trial and error.

Comment: @pguardiario It's the part of the multi-part MIME document that you want to retrieve. E.g. text/plain, text/html...

Answer (score 11):

My solution (works with all types and charset) :

```
function format_html($str) {
    // Convertit tous les caractères éligibles en entités HTML en convertissant les codes ASCII 10 en $lf
    $str = htmlentities($str, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
    $str = str_replace(chr(10), "<br>", $str);
    return $str;
}


// Start

$obj_structure = imap_fetchstructure($imapLink, $obj_mail->msgno);

// Recherche de la section contenant le corps du message et extraction du contenu
$obj_section = $obj_structure;
$section = "1";
for ($i = 0 ; $i < 10 ; $i++) {
    if ($obj_section->type == 0) {
        break;
    } else {
        $obj_section = $obj_section->parts[0];
        $section.= ($i > 0 ? ".1" : "");
    }
}
$text = imap_fetchbody($imapLink, $obj_mail->msgno, $section);
// Décodage éventuel
if ($obj_section->encoding == 3) {
    $text = imap_base64($text);
} else if ($obj_section->encoding == 4) {
    $text = imap_qprint($text);
}
// Encodage éventuel
foreach ($obj_section->parameters as $obj_param) {
    if (($obj_param->attribute == "charset") && (mb_strtoupper($obj_param->value) != "UTF-8")) {
        $text = utf8_encode($text);
        break;
    }
}

// End
print format_html($text);
```

Comment: This one should be accepted. Works for more types of emails than the current accepted answer. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You Can also try these

```
content-type:text/html

$message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number, 2);

content-type:plaintext/text

$message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number, 1);
```