# How to extract only HTML from imap_body result

Tags: php, html, imap

**I want to extract only the HTML content from a imap_body result.
The imap_body give a verbatim copy of the mail.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract body text from Email PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272551/extract-body-text-from-email-php)

Comment: `imap_fetchbody($inbox, $number, 2);` worked for me

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**I found a solution:**

```
function getBody($uid, $imap)
{
    $body = $this->get_part($imap, $uid, "TEXT/HTML");
    // if HTML body is empty, try getting text body
    if ($body == "") {
        $body = $this->get_part($imap, $uid, "TEXT/PLAIN");
    }
    return $body;
}

function get_part($imap, $uid, $mimetype, $structure = false, $partNumber = false)
{
    if (!$structure) {
        $structure = imap_fetchstructure($imap, $uid, FT_UID);
    }
    if ($structure) {
        if ($mimetype == $this->get_mime_type($structure)) {
            if (!$partNumber) {
                $partNumber = 1;
            }
            $text = imap_fetchbody($imap, $uid, $partNumber, FT_UID);
            switch ($structure->encoding) {
                case 3:
                    return imap_base64($text);
                case 4:
                    return imap_qprint($text);
                default:
                    return $text;
            }
        }

        // multipart
        if ($structure->type == 1) {
            foreach ($structure->parts as $index => $subStruct) {
                $prefix = "";
                if ($partNumber) {
                    $prefix = $partNumber . ".";
                }
                $data = $this->get_part($imap, $uid, $mimetype, $subStruct, $prefix . ($index + 1));
                if ($data) {
                    return $data;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function get_mime_type($structure)
{
    $primaryMimetype = ["TEXT", "MULTIPART", "MESSAGE", "APPLICATION", "AUDIO", "IMAGE", "VIDEO", "OTHER"];

    if ($structure->subtype) {
        return $primaryMimetype[(int)$structure->type] . "/" . $structure->subtype;
    }
    return "TEXT/PLAIN";
}
```

Comment: great solution!

Comment: gave the HTML output perfectly

Answer (score 8):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchbody.php

Parameter 3, "the section" is as follows:

> The part number. It is a string of integers delimited by period which index into a body part list as per the IMAP4 specification

```
(empty) - Entire message
0 - Message header
1 - MULTIPART/ALTERNATIVE
1.1 - TEXT/PLAIN
1.2 - TEXT/HTML
2 - file.ext
```

Therefore, to grab the HTML part of the mail, you would have to use the 1.2 option as the third parameter. Like so:

```
$message = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $number, 1.2);
```

Comment: This only applies /if/ the message follows this structure.  Many emails do not, and they will not follow this structure if it includes attachments.  The best way method is to parse the bodystructure to find the HTML section you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunatly, i tried this method but it didn't work.

Comment: @Max can you help me with a method for body structure.

Comment: `imap_fetchbody($inbox, $number, 2);` worked for me

Answer (score 4):

I don't have enough reputation to add a comment, but I just wanted to clarify in @GunniH's answer that your call to the function should look like this:

`$message = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $number, '1.2');`

instead of this

`$message = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $number, 1.2);`

That final argument should be a `string`, not an `int`.

Comment: 1.2 is not an int but a float. But both inputs should work.

Comment: `imap_fetchbody($inbox, $number, 2);` worked for me